# how to add a "add user" tab to admin/people

Tags: users

Currently on the user administration page admin/people there is a link below the tab row that lets admins add users (links to admin/people/create). Instead I would like to place that link in an additional tab next to the tabs "list" and "permissions". Has anybody experience in this? Or is there even a module for this?

I currently have difficulties finding anything because "add user tab" are quite generic search terms and there is a lot to find – but not meeting my problem.

*thank you!*

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is the same as this.  Apologies if not.

Here I've added a menu item that links out to another page.  So you should be able to change the links to your needs.  For this I created a module 'taskmenuextras'

```
    **
* Implementation of hook_menu_alter
*/
function taskmenuextras_menu_alter(&$items) {
    $items['user/%user/featuredjobs'] = array(
        'title' => t('Featured Jobs'),
        'page callback' => 'taskmenuextras_redirect_nodequeue',
        'access callback' => 'taskmenuextras_user_has_role',
        'access arguments' => array(1, array('admin')),
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK, 
        'weight'  => 0,
        ); 


    return $items;
}


function taskmenuextras_redirect_nodequeue() {
  drupal_goto('admin/structure/nodequeue/featured_jobs/view/1');
}

function taskmenuextras_user_has_role($user, $roles = array()) {  
  foreach ($roles as $role) {
    if (in_array($role, $user->roles)) {
      return TRUE;
    }
  }
  return FALSE;  
}
```